# How to transfer file via wireless from iOS device to PC on the same Network?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a database file on my iPhone application. I want to copy it and transfer to my PC that connected to the same network.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html) to share a file. One of the available options will be [AirDrop](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106), that will enable sending the file to the Mac.

Comment: 1.I need transfer a file to Windows, airDrop is for Mac i think.
2. I need it running without user interaction